# Prove that $f(x)=e^x$ on the interval $[0,1]$ is integrable using under and over step functions.

Tags: integration, proof-verification

I have made an attempt at proving that $f(x)=e^x$ is integrable on the interval $[0,1]$ using a theorem involving under and over step functions. Is there anything that I am missing or is this enough?

My attempt in the image below:

[image: Question and attempt at proof]

Comment: I realized that $n$ should be $n > \frac{e-1}{\varepsilon}$

Comment: Looks good to me, aside from that minor detail that you pointed out. In the future please type your work using MathJax directly into the site. The image is a bit hard to read and I had to zoom in considerably to make out the details. (Images like your plot of the step functions and $e^x$ are of course fine to include.)

Comment: Thank you, it's my first post and wasn't sure how TeX works on here. I'll make sure to type it out next time!